# SQL - How to Aggregate and Sort a Parent Child Tree?

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

I have the following tables. A job can be classified under multiple categories. A category has a parent category. Categories only go two levels deep. Jobs are only classified under the second level category. I want a list of all categories with a count of jobs that are classified for each category and total for the parent category.

Below are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE jobs (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    description text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE categories (
   id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   parent_id INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE job_categories (
    job_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    category_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`job_id`, `category_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_job_id(job_id) REFERENCES jobs(id),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_category_id(category_id) REFERENCES categories(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


INSERT INTO categories (id, name, parent_id) VALUES(1, 'Science', 0),(2, 'Biology', 1), (3, 'Chemistry', 1);
INSERT INTO job_categories (job_id, category_id) VALUES(1,2),(1,3), (2,2), (3,2), (4,3);
```

This is my SQL attempt:

```
SELECT one.name AS name
     , one.name AS sortkey1
     , CAST(NULL AS UNSIGNED) AS sortkey2
     , COUNT(three.job_id) AS total 
  FROM categories AS one
  INNER JOIN categories AS two ON two.parent_id = one.id
  LEFT JOIN job_categories AS three ON three.category_id = two.id
  WHERE one.parent_id = 0
  GROUP BY name, sortkey1, sortkey2
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('  ',two.name) AS name
     , one.name AS sortkey1
     , two.name AS sortkey2
     , COUNT(three.job_id) AS total 
  FROM categories AS one
  INNER JOIN categories AS two ON two.parent_id = one.id
  LEFT JOIN job_categories AS three ON three.category_id = two.id
  WHERE one.parent_id = 0
  GROUP BY name, sortkey1, sortkey2
ORDER BY sortkey1 , sortkey2
```

This is the what I'm trying to achieve for example if 4 jobs are posted and 3 of the jobs are classified under biology and 2 of the 4 are classified under chemistry - the above sql doesnt give the right total for the parent category science. I get 5 instead of 4:

```
name            sortkey1      sortkey2     total
Science         Science                     4 
   Biology      Science       Biology       3
   Chemistry    Science       Chemistry     2
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: @JeffUK there's only two levels, `category_types` and `categories`. Jobs are classified under `categories` but I want to list both `category_types` and `categories`

Comment: @adam78 Can u provide the sample data for each table from which you are expecting above-mentioned output?

Comment: @JeffUK nope not a duplicate. The post you are reffering to is using sql server. This is for Mysql which doesn't support any of the fucntions such as partion etc used in the post you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT one.name AS name
 , one.name AS sortkey1
 , CAST(NULL AS UNSIGNED) AS sortkey2
 , COUNT(DISTINCT three.job_id) AS total 
FROM categories AS one
INNER JOIN categories AS two ON two.parent_id = one.id
LEFT JOIN job_categories AS three ON three.category_id = two.id
WHERE one.parent_id = 0
GROUP BY name, sortkey1, sortkey2
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('  ',two.name) AS name
 , one.name AS sortkey1
 , two.name AS sortkey2
 , COUNT(three.job_id) AS total 
FROM categories AS one
INNER JOIN categories AS two ON two.parent_id = one.id
LEFT JOIN job_categories AS three ON three.category_id = two.id
WHERE one.parent_id = 0
GROUP BY name, sortkey1, sortkey2
ORDER BY sortkey1 , sortkey2
```